# how to exclude library project in secondary dex android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ant

I am facing 65k method limit exceed, for this i am using secondary dex mechanism, I was created multiple library project , When i tried to create build via ant, it is include all library project and make dex of all library project as well, I am using [this](https://github.com/mmin18/Dex65536) to create apk, it is works fine and create apk, but some of library project is not working , So is that any way to exclude some library project or any way to exclude jar file in library project